# QML AnimatedImage: Error Reading Animated Image File qrc:/myimage.gif

Tags: qt, qml, gif

How to make gif files work in `qt`?

I get the following error:

```
QML AnimatedImage: Error Reading Animated Image File qrc:/untitled/images/Pivot_Wave.gif
```

If I run the code below:

```cpp
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: 'green'

        AnimatedImage {
            id: animation

            x: 100; y: 50
            width: 200; height: 200

            source: 'images/Pivot_Wave.gif'
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the gif itself:

[image]

qrc file:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your resource file?

Comment: from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html#source-prop): _AnimatedImage can handle any image format supported by Qt, loaded from any URL scheme supported by Qt_. Accordingly, you have a problem with either the format or the Url. As I see you use **relative** path instead of `qrc`, see [this note](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html#using-the-url-type) : _When referring to files stored with the Qt Resource System from within QML, you should use "qrc:///" ..._. if you want to use `qrc` you have to do it explicitly

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @folibis I have tried 'qrc:///images/Pivot_Wave.gif', which gives me the same error but with this path `qrc:///images/Pivot_Wave.gif`. qrc with 2 slashes doesn't throw the error `qrc://images/Pivot_Wave.gif`, but it still doesn't show the gif. @JarMan I have updated the question with the resource file.

Comment: @sunwarr10r show the .qrc content (not gif images)

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated the question. There was no qrc file, so I added one and it is empty, but I can add a prefix to it.

Comment: @sunwarr10r Open the .qrc with any text editor (eg notepad) and copy the content. Please provide a [mre] : .pro, .cpp, etc.

Comment: it has the following content `<RCC/>`

Comment: Sounds a bit strange for me that you refer to qrc that doesn't exist or empty. Add a prefix (probably /), add your file to this prefix and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did't know that it is necessary to have a `Resource Collection File` in my project to load images and `Qt` also didn't create one automatically for me.

So I created one myself by right clicking inside the File System and then `Add New...` --> `Qt` --> `Qt Resource File`

I copied the example from this website https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html and adopted it to my project:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/Pivot_Wave.gif</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: did that solve the issue?